# Haskell - how to return a list of a list of all of the rows of elements in a grid

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I am working on a generic version of the game connect 4 in which you can select the size of the grid as well as the number of pieces needed to connect in order to win.  I am working on a function now that will check which player won.  I am trying to break it down into four smaller parts.  I have already implemented a function to return the columns, but am stuck on rows as well as diagonals both ways across the grid.  I am new to Haskell and am struggling to stop thinking about these problems in an OO way.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this problem for quite a while now.

```
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

data Piece = Yellow | Red    

type Column = [Piece]   
type Board = [Column]

data BoardState = BS {
  theBoard :: Board,
  lastMove :: Piece,
  numColumns :: Int,
  numRows :: Int,
  numToConnect :: Int }

repeatNothing :: Int -> [Maybe a]
repeatNothing m = replicate m Nothing

padN :: [a] -> Int -> [Maybe a]
padN xs n = (map Just xs) ++ repeatNothing (n - (length xs))

columns :: BoardState -> [[Maybe Piece]]
columns bs = map (\col -> padN col (numRows bs)) (theBoard bs)

rows :: BoardState -> [[Maybe Piece]]
rows bs = map (\row -> padN row (numColumns bs)) (theBoard bs)

diagonalsForward :: BoardState -> [[Maybe Piece]]
diagonalsForward = undefined

diagonalsBackward :: BoardState -> [[Maybe Piece]]
diagonalsBackward = undefined
```

Comment: For this game, I would probably represent the board by an indexed structure rather than a list of lists. Maybe even `Data.Map (Int,Int) Piece`. Then the complexity of finding rows columns and diagonals is mainly just generating the appropriate `[(Int,Int)]` lists, which ought to be a few simple list comprehensions.

Comment: I would suggest to define `data Piece = Yellow | Red | None` instead of returning `Maybe Piece`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saying you're learning Haskell, I'm going to just give you some hints:

1. If you have `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]` as the list of columns, then the list of rows `[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]` is exactly the `transpose` of the columns.
2. The main diagonal (going down-right) of columns `(x:_):cs` is `x` followed by the main diagonal of the columns `cs`, without their first row.
3. All the (down-right going) diagonals of the columns `c:cs` is the diagonal of `c:cs` followed by all the diagonals of the columns `cs`
4. To get the diagonals going down-left, it's enough to `reverse` the order of columns and then get the down-right going diagonals of that.

Answer (score 1):

If you define the Piece as an open slot

```
data Piece = Yellow | Red | Empty deriving Show
let Board = replicate n $ replicate m Empty
```

You can test whether there are 4 in a row by pattern matching on

```
pre:Yellow:Yellow:Yellow:Yellow:post
```

To test if Yellow has 4 in a row

Similar pattern matching could be done on the transpose of the list of lists.